# Is there a tool to draw a graph representation of my c++ classes and methods?

Tags: c++, object, graph

Is there a tool to draw a graph representation of my c++ classes and methods ?

---

In other words -- as G++ may do it already to check for circular dependencies between headers -- is there a tool that can actually show me how my classes and methods interact with each other ?

---

**Not** an exact duplicate of [Class dependency tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544274/class-dependency-tool)

> I'd like to be able to not only see **static** dependencies between classes but also between methods.

Is there an open source tool, or at least working under Linux?

Comment: Adding more [info to your elaboration `I'd like to be able to not only see (static) dependencies between classes but also between methods`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6108616/is-there-a-tool-to-draw-a-graph-representation-of-my-c-classes-and-methods/6108643#6108643)

Comment: I do not thank the five people who voted to close this question, leaving it unanswered.

Answer (score 3):

[doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/) does a neat job of it. I suggest using the DoxyWizard GUI.

See online demos: [<strike>http://www.doxygen.nl/results.html</strike>](http://www.doxygen.nl/results.html)
This is a better link, though very very simple:

http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/examples/diagrams/html/inherits.html

It serves as a demonstration of principles in the documentation for graphing in Doxygen:

http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/diagrams.html

If you want to do heavy-weight analysis, look at [CppDepend](http://www.cppdepend.com).

---

As an answer to the request for dynamic call graphs, may I suggest [KCachegrind](http://kcachegrind.sourceforge.net/html/Screenshots.html)

It works well on linux (and MacOS, per the comment) in combination with Callgrind:

```
valgrind --tool=callgrind ./myprogram
kcachegrind
```

Presto! But valgrind only works on linux. I know there are quite a few profilers that have output convertors to kcachegrind readable format. I don't use them, so I'm afraid there would be some google work in it for you

[image]

Comment: Is there no way to graph it with Doxygen ? The examples on the page don't show graphs.

Comment: EEVa: Put in a better link. Still quite spartan, not as exciting as a real codebase, but serves the purpose now (_amazing how the demos don't show off this awesome feature of Doxygen..._)

Comment: Valgrind also works on Mac OS X

Comment: Fortunately I'm a Linux user :D